# Jsch auth fail using public key

Tags: java

I am trying to establish scp connection to a server but I am having the problem while connecting to server. It throws the below exception

> com.jcraft.JschExceltion : Auth fail

While using password approach, i am able to connect but when using the public key approach, its not connecting.

I have also added hosts file. Below is the code fragment :

```
....
jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa");                         
jsch.addKnownHosts("~/.ssh/known_hosts");
....
```

Comment: How about posting more of your error?

Comment: Reported above comment to moderator: please keep it civil here.

Answer (score 0):

Java libraries don't generally expand `~`, and that expansion isn't done at the OS level, either. When you use that expansion in a shell, the shell itself is doing the substitution.

In other words, your code is looking for files in a directory literally named `~`, relative to your program's working directory.

Instead, you should get the user's home directory using [`System.getProperty("user.home")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), and build a path relative to that.